# Longest Collatz sequence in Scala

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, comparative-review, scala, memoization, collatz-sequence

I am trying to [find the longest Collatz Sequence](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler014/problem):

> Which starting number, ≤ *N*, produces the longest chain? If many possible such numbers are there print the maximum one.  (1 ≤ *N* ≤ 5×10<sup>6</sup>)

I tried optimizing the code to include memoization still getting Time Limit Exceeded, for these solutions. Wanted some help to understand where the method is consuming time.

**Implementation Using HashMap As Memoized Cache:**

```
object CollatzSeq {
  private final val mapOfCollatzSequence = 
    scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[BigInt, BigInt]()
      .withDefaultValue(0)

  def longestCollatzSeq(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
    def longestCollatzSeqHelper(n: BigInt, count: BigInt = 0): BigInt = {
      val mapValueOfN = mapOfCollatzSequence(n)
      n match {
        case n if n == 1 => count
        case _ if mapValueOfN != 0 =>
          count + mapValueOfN
        case n if n % 2 == 0 =>
          val updateForEven = longestCollatzSeqHelper(n/2, count + 1)
          mapOfCollatzSequence.update(n, updateForEven - count)
          updateForEven
        case n if n % 2 != 0 =>
          val c = longestCollatzSeqHelper(3 * n + 1 , count + 1)
          mapOfCollatzSequence.update(n, c - count)
          c
      }
    }
    longestCollatzSeqHelper(n)
  }
}
```

**Implementation Using Array As Memoized Cache:**

```
object CollatzSeq {

  // Using Array As Performance Is Better Than Map
  private final val collatzSeq = Array.fill[BigInt](5* 1000 * 1000)(0)
  def longestCollatzSeq(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
    def longestCollatzSeqHelper(n: BigInt, count: BigInt = 0): BigInt = {
      val countOfN = collatzSeq((n - 1).toInt)
      n match {
        case n if n == 1 => count
        case _ if countOfN != 0 =>
          count + countOfN
        case n if n % 2 == 0 =>
          val updateForEven = longestCollatzSeqHelper(n/2, count + 1)
          collatzSeq.update((n-1).toInt, updateForEven - count)
          updateForEven
        case n if n % 2 != 0 =>
          val updateForOdd = longestCollatzSeqHelper(3 * n + 1 , count + 1)
          collatzSeq.update((n-1).toInt, updateForOdd - count)
          updateForOdd
      }
    }
    longestCollatzSeqHelper(n)
  }
}
```

[**Performance Reference**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

Comment: Hey welcome to Code Review! Please add some description about what problem your code solves (i.e. a quote from the the problem description). This is because links can rot and a question should be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: @Graipher, Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could do to make what you've got a bit faster:

1. The numbers get quite big but `BigInt` is overkill (and slow). The `longestCollatzSeqHelper()` method will have to deal with values in the `Long` domain, but the problem set, and results, are well within the `Int` range, which will be faster.
2. Because of the large numbers, you're cache could grow immensely. Perhaps beyond system resources.
3. You're testing `n` as many as 4 times per iteration. That can be reduced to 2.

But this is mere window dressing. When you encounter HackerRank timeout limits, code optimization usually doesn't get you very far. 9 times out of 10 you need to go back, re-examine the problem statement, and rethink your approach to it.

When I tackled this problem I started by caching calculations, but eventually I gave that up and started focusing on the other end:

1. To find the longest Collatz length for numbers <= N, I don't have to count the Collatz length for *every* number below N. There's a threshold below which it is impossible for the C-length to surpass the lengths for numbers above that threshold.
2. Some numbers don't need to have their Collatz length calculated at all. Due to a simple mathematical property it is impossible for its C-length to surpass its neighbors.

With this in mind, and caching for reuse only individual results within a problem set, you should be able to pass this challenge.